# How to write a code in Python to sum integers without using sum function?

Tags: python

Here's my task:
In this task you have to simply sum some integers.
However, to make it more interesting you cannot use in your code the following:
for, while, sum, map, reduce, filter, import, eval, exec, compile, single
Input Format
One line with some number of space-separated integers a1, a2, a3, ..., an
Output Format
One number, that is the sum of all ai

I've tried this code:

```
def recursive_s(numbers_str):
    if not numbers_str:
        return []
    else:
        return [int(numbers_str[0])] + recursive_s(numbers_str[1:])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_str = input().strip()
    numbers = recursive_s(input_str.split())

    result = recursive_s(numbers)
    print(sum(result))`
```

But i dont know how to avoid using sum or any other functions it says i cant use in the task`your text`

Answer (score 1):

You were close, use `int`s instead of `list`. You also remove one of the calls to `recursive_s`

```
def recursive_s(numbers_str):
    if not numbers_str:
        return 0
    else:
        return int(numbers_str[0]) + recursive_s(numbers_str[1:])


input_str = input().strip()
result = recursive_s(input_str.split())
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a way of doing it avoiding all the keywords that are "not allowed".

```py
nums = "2 4 6 8"
nums_list = nums.split()

def my_sum(nums):
    if not nums: 
        return 0
    head = nums[0]
    tail = nums[1:]    
    return int(head) + my_sum(tail)

sum = my_sum(nums_list)  
print(sum)
```

i craftily use list slicing to achieve this.

As a side note, recursive functions are often (always) beaten by non-iterative and memoized functions: https://youtu.be/1podU0jN4aU

Answer (score 0):

For fun and out of spite for such restrictions...

A tricky solution using `list` and [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) for iteration ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3szNLFGwVMktSizQy8wpKSzQ09YoLcjKBtCZXMVDGgCslNU0hMSVFQ9OKSwEI0nPykxJzFIrBnGIFbaDmvBKNvNSKEo3MEqCmnMxiEAtoHlCTjoIBUKigCKSkWBNi5QIYZahgpGAM4QAA)):

```py
it = iter(input().split())
s = 0
def add():
    global s
    s += int(next(it))
list(iter(add, 0))
print(s)
```

A loophole solution, following not the spirit but the letter of the rules ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3-xOLSxRsFeLjk0ozc0oy84rj4_Xi4zNzC_KLSuLjNdSB0uqaXLmJJRn4VIHkgcq4Cooy80o0QBgkopdWXJqrATRBLyezJLUoMSc-tSwxR0NdR10vKz8zD6iuoLREQ1OvuAAor6EJBhBnLYBRhgpGCsYQDgA)):

```py
ast = __builtins__.__import__('ast')
math = __builtins__.__import__('math')

print(int(math.fsum(ast.literal_eval(','.join(input().split())))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def custom_sum(*args):
    if not args:
        return 0
    else:
        return args[0] + custom_sum(*args[1:])

# Read input
input_numbers = input().split()
input_numbers = [int(num) for num in input_numbers]

# Calculate and print the sum
result = custom_sum(*input_numbers)
print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**